# Delete rows from multiple tables based on a single input

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have three tables:

```
estate_field_data
estate_field_types
estate_fields
```

And the only input i have from the browser is `estate_field_types.ID = 3`

`estate_fields` contains a definition for `estate_field_types.ID => estate_fields.FieldType`

But `estate_field_data` does not have a definition for the `estate_field_types.ID`, but instead a `estate_field_data.FieldID => estate_fields.ID`

How can I delete from all three rows with this single value?

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it as 3 separate statements (unless you've set up cascading deletes on your foreign key references). I'm assuming there's a PK in `estate_fields` (I've chosen to call it `estate_field_id`) which `estate_field_data` references (otherwise, I'm unsure how we identify what to delete from that table)

```
delete from estate_field_data where estate_field_id in (select estate_field_id from estate_fields where FieldType = 3)

delete from estate_fields where FieldType = 3

delete from estate_field_types where ID = 3
```

Comment: Exactly! It was the "IN"-clause that was missing! :-) Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try with joins as well....
Damien ... Should we suggest OP for Joins usage? May be quicker in OP case?

```
Delete K From estate_field_data K
Inner Join estate_fields F on F.estate_field_id = K.estate_field_id
Where F.estate_field_id = 3
```

Comment: Should the estate_field_types then be deleted in a second statement?

Comment: rest you can follow Damien's suggestion.... But I want to suggest Joins in place of In statement.. Will be quicker in deletion....

Comment: @meep - you'd still need to do 3 separate deletes - there's no way for a delete (or insert/update) to affect more than one table (directly - such a statement against a table with triggers or cascading deletes on foreign keys may end up affecting multiple tables)

Comment: I wouldn't expect any speed difference. Both queries would need to access the estate_field_id of estate_fields, with a filter criteria against FieldType, and both queries need to filter estate_field_data based on estate_field_id - the same indexes would assist both queries (or the lack of indexes would hinder both queries)

Comment: I'd stick with Damien. But nice to learn various ways of doing this.

Comment: hmmm... May be your are right. I think, it should matter in case you have bulk of records to delete..It's a sort of loop in IN statement which I felt in my past experience and shocked me after the joins usuage